# How can i store values in my dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**bag contains:**

```
['Item','item','item']
```

**coins contains:**

```
['Item','Item','Item']

coin_to_bag = {}
print('Here are your bags:\n')
print(bags)
print('\n')
print('Here are your coin types:\n')
print (coins)
```

**my nested loop**

```
bags =  ['small', 'medium','large']
coins = ['quarter', 'dime', 'nickel', 'penny']


'''
what Im trying to do:
foreach bag in bags:
    print: enter in a coin index. e.g. 1 for quarter out of ['quarter', 'dime', 'nickel', 'penny']
    prompt:: how many of this type?         15  (thus will store '15' representing, there are 15 quarters, storing '15')
    for index_position in coins:
        assign index, type = bag            create a dictionary like ["quarter"] = {"1", "15"}}
    print(coin_to_bag)      

'''
for bag in bags:
    coin_to_bag = coin_to_bag[bag]   # set quarter as a key in coin_to_bag = {["quarter"]}
    coin_type = input('Number of this type? e.g. type 1 for Quarter "["Quarter", "Nickel"]" ')  #e.g. 0.25 * 2
    coin_amount = input('Number of this type?   e.g. 15')  #e.g. 0.25 * 2
    for coin in coins:
        #set values for key: quarter like {["quarter"] = ["1", "15"]}
        coin_to_bag[bag] = coin_to_bag[coin_type], coin_to_bag[coin_amount]  

print(coin_to_bag)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to use my `dictionary` and `lists(coin,bags)`

Ultimately I'm trying to get `coin_to_bag` to store:

```
coin_to_bag = {"small": {"1", "15"}, "medium": {"2", "5"}  }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What is "my nested loop"?  Why are "bag contains:" and "coins contains:" different from `bads = ` and `coins = `?

Comment: This question is SO unclear %)
if you want to store an array in dictionary you can do this:
`coin_to_bag = {'small': ['1', '15'], 'medium': ['2', '5']}`

Comment: Please see coin_to_bag in the statement, thats what im trying to get into that dictionary

Comment: I want to be able to store the values from coin and bag in coin_to_bag variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Values are stored to dictionaries in this way:

```
some_dict = {}
some_dict[key] = value
```

Or in one line as: `some_dict = {key: value}`.

So presumably, you want:

```
coin_to_bag[bag] = [coin_type, coin_amount]
```

For example this might mean,

```
coin_to_bag['small'] = ["1", "15"]
```

Doing this, `coin_to_bag[bag]` means access the element of the `coin_to_bag` dictionary with the key given by `bag`.  But that key-value won't exist until you set it.

Comment: If I may, your example is of a dictionary literal, not a dictionary comprehension. Dictionary comprehension involves a for loop, just like list comprehension: `my_dict = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(some_list)}`